# Error using stickyUp.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla

I'm using **stickyUp.js** for my website on local host.

I followed the instructions from the website itself of stickyUp, but I've tried several times and got nothing. I used firebug and found out the error message:

> The  jQuery('.navbar-wrapper').stickUp(); is not a function”

Could someone help me with  this?

Comment: How are you importing the script? What version of Joomla are you using? Make sure you don't have multiple jQuery libraries being imported as this can cause conflicts

Comment: Hi Lodder,

I’m using Joomla 3.3.6, I used gantry template I import stickyUp.js file via templates > template Name >index.php > head adding like this $gantry->addScript('stickUp.js');
Actually, i have multiple libraries being imported to my index.php. I also add noConflict but still got an error.

Comment: Make sure you put `<?php $gantry->addScript('stickUp.js'); ?>` inside the `<head>` tags in your *index.php* and that the file has been placed in the correct location.